# What can I do to get k8s to return json in the form of an underscore instead of a camel case

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I need to use client-go to get the state of deployment in k8s, but when json serialization is done, k8s is serialized by camel case by default, while I need to pass it to the front end in the form of underscore division. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom marshaling function for transforming the JSON output from camel case to snake case or you can use this package that does the exact same [thing](https://github.com/Rican7/conjson)